# How to convert int array to integer

Tags: c#

I want to convert int array to int so i can add them.

Example

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3};

sum=x[0] + x[1] + x[2];
```

I have a loop for getting an input from user but i have to add all the values of every inputted.

Comment: What's the issue you have with the code you've provided?

Comment: plenty of ways to convert an array into an integer.... first, last, middle, average, mean, sum, factorial progression, LCD, GCF.....

Comment: @Llama I think the problem is it is not flexible regarding the length of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.Sum` LINQ method:

```cs
var x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var sum = x.Sum(); // gives 6
```

## Further info

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/
- https://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-sum/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a number of ways.

first by making a loop yourself.

```
static int Sum(int[] array)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            foreach (var item in array)
            {
                sum += item;
            }
            return sum;
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            int[] x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            Console.Write(Sum(x).ToString());
        }
```

second, using the Sum() method in the `System.Linq` library

```
using System.Linq;

////
int[] x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.Write(x.Sum());
```

thank you `USEFUL` for feedback if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear what the problem is.  Your code seems fully functional, so it is difficult to know what you are really trying to achieve and what the underlying issue it.

But certainly a simple loop would work fine.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int loop=0; loop < x.Length; loop++)
{
    sum += x[loop];
}
```

You can also do this via Linq (I see somebody else posted that example, so I won't repeat it).